# Do own stuff in Slick transaction

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'm using Slick 3.1.1 and i would like to implement my own stuff on Slick transaction.

```
def findSomeProducts = table.getSomeProducts() //db operation
def productTableUpdate = doSomeStuff1() //db operation
def priceTableUpdate = doSomeStuff2() //db operation

def updateElasticCache = updateIndexOfProduct() //this is not a database operation
```

I have these sample functions. Firstly, I'm getting some products from db and after i'm updating the tables. At the end I need to run updateElasticCache method. If updateElasticCache method fails, I would like to rollback whole db procceses.

I can't use 
`(for { ... } yield ()).transactionally` this code because it's not applicable for my cases. This 'transactionally' is waiting a db action. But I want to add another functionality which is not a db-process.

Is it possible? How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**DBIO.from**

*Yes !!! its possible to add non db logic in between db logic in slick using DBIO actions composition and `DBIO.from`*

*Note that "your own stuff" should return a future*, future can be converted to DBIO and can be composed along with usual db actions.

`DBIO.from` can help you with this. Here is how it works. `DBIO.from` takes a future and converts it into a DBIOAction. now you can compose these actions with usual db actions to do non-db operations along with db operations in a transaction.

```
def updateElasticCache: Future[Unit] = Future(doSomething())
```

now lets say we have some db actions

```
def createUser(user: User): DBIO[Int] = ???
```

I want createUser to rollback if updating cache fails. so i do the following

```
val action = createUser.flatMap { _ => DBIO.from(updateElasticCache()) }.transactionally
db.run(action)
```

now if `updateElasticCache` fails whole `tx` will fail and everything will rollback to normal state.

**Example**

*You can use for comprehension to make it look good*

```
def updateStats: DBIO[Int] = ???
val rollbackActions =
  (for {
     cStatus <- createUser()
     uStatus <- updateStats()
     result <- DBIO.from(updateElasticCache())
   } yield result).transactionally
 db.run(rollbackActions)
```

everything roll backs if `updateElasticCache` future fails

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to refactor my functions. My db-operation function's return type is different from DBIO. Instead of DBIO[T], it returns JdbcProfile.this.DriverAction[Int, NoStream, Write]. 
`
def testUpdate(productId: Int, text: String): JdbcProfile.this.DriverAction[Int, NoStream, Write] = {
    val q = for { p <- Products if p.id === productId } yield (p.text)
    q.update(text)
  }
`
Sorry, I've just started to learn Slick today. I don't know is it a logical question?

Comment: @sydboraa `updateElasticCache()` should return `Future[_]` and then you could wrap it in `DBIO.from(updateElasticCache())`. or `def updateElasticCache: DBIO[_] = DBIO.from { doSomething() }` `doSomething` in turn returns `Future[_]`.

Comment: @sydboraa `DBIO` is the type alias for `DriverAction`

Comment: what kind of import is necessary for .transactionally method?